# Free tool to migrate from Sybase SQL Anywhere 12 to MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-migration, sqlanywhere

I need to recover data from a Sybase SQL Anywhere 12 (I have an *.db file) into MS SQL Server 2008.

I installed the SQL Anywhere 12 Developer kit and that allowed me to run the database and installed ODBC drivers that should have allowed me to do this. I managed to use the SQL Server Import/Export wizard to import a single table by typing in an SQL statement, the import all data functionality was disabled.

Since I have a hundred or so tables, I'd like to find a tool to automatically do the import for me, for all tables. Are there any free tools or scripts out there for this?

Comment: Maybe this shareware can do the job http://www.brothersoft.com/mysql-sybase-sql-anywhere-import-export-57047.html

Comment: This will be usefull, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25355/how-to-import-sybase-db-file-into-sql-server-database  the software is in this page http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/migration-tool.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f39d6150-e611-46e1-84c5-0808010711c8&displaylang=en

I'm not very keen on Sybase versions, but maybe it is what you are looking for

Comment: I don't know much about Sybase versions either, but I think this one is for another more powerful version of Sybase. I installed the tool and it prompts me for server information which I don't think I have when just accessing a file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly there isnt any freewhere tools to do it, however, one trick I use is to migrate the data from Sybase into Access (using ODBC), and then upsize from there to SQL Server.